# How to resume an HTTP download served by Apache and svn module?

Tags: apache, svn, apache2

I 'm using Collabnet Subversion server 1.7.6(on Windows); I store large files(30M+) in SVN repository and serve them via the bundled Apache HTTP server(2.2.22).

I find that download of SVN-served files does not support resume. In HTTP protocol term, the client requests `Range: xxx-` in HTTP header, but the server does not respond with HTTP header `Content-Range: xxx-yyy` , so the client has to download from the first byte of a file.

I also try http download resume on Apache website's svn server.

```
wget -c http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/1.7.x/CHANGES
```

I press Ctrl+C in the middle of download, then `wget -c` again, the same result.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Short of implementing the missing `Range` support in Collabnet Subversion server, or posting a support request to Collabnet, I doubt it.

Comment: If you are willing to run unreleased code, there is a workaround -- http://serverfault.com/questions/431228